# Understanding the line between Objective-C and Foundation, specifically NSString

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, I can write:

```
id pString = @"Hello, World.";
```

and the compiler will instantiate an NSString without me needing to explicitly call a factory method.  However, NSString is really just a Foundation class and thus presumably not part of the actual Objective-C language definition.

So when I write `@"String"`, how does the compiler know to build an NSString in particular, and not some other string-like object?  In other words, where does the Objective-C *language* stop and the Foundation *library* start?

Comment: `@""` is part of `objective-c` definition, it instantiates `NSString` object ... as opposed to plain `char *` string defined in `c` with `""`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write Objective-C code outside of Cocoa or GNUStep environments, `@"..."` is not linked to `NSString`.

In this case, gcc provides an option for specifying a class associated to literal strings:

*-fconstant-string-class=class-name*

Use class-name as the name of the class to instantiate for each
literal string specified with the syntax "@"..."".  The default
class name is "NXConstantString".

Comment: This link provides a bit more info:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constant-string-objects.html

Comment: is there a way to use that compiler flag implicitly, so I won't have to keep writing it every time I want to compile?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee - Put it in a Makefile.

Comment: @mouviciel that doesn't help if it's a library I'm making

Answer (score 3):

The `@""` directive appears to be built-in to the objective-c compiler.

For instance, if you remove all `#import`s from your .m source file (& prefix header), the following line will be a syntax error:

`NSString *string = @"ABCD"; // (Doesn't know anything about NSString class)`

However, if you change the Foundation `NSString` type to the built-in `void` type, it will compile just fine:

`void *string = @"ABCD";`

So, even without Foundation's `NSString` definition, the compiler knows how to turn `@""` into something that can become an `NSString` instance at runtime (it probably won't instantiate without Foundation, but the compiler doesn't seem to mind); Since it accepts the syntax without needing any external library definitions, the compiler sees `@""` as part of the language.

Your code, however, won't be able to make use of any `@""` instance without importing Foundation.h, so from the point of view of your program, `@""` is part of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting bit is that an Objective-C string literal (`@""` notation) returns the same type as an explicitly instantiated `NSString` object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    printf("string literal class: %s\n", object_getClassName(@"a string literal"););

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"asdf"];
    printf("explicit NSString class: %s", object_getClassName(str));

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

I vaguely remember that in other, older implementations of Objective-C, the string literal actually returned an object of a slightly different class, but that could be used interchangeably with `NSString`/`NSCFString`. Not totally sure on that part, though.